# What is the java.lang.Integer retained size?

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm, yourkit, memory-footprint

I'm using Java Hotspot 1.8.0_191-b12 (64 bit, Xmx < 32 GB) and I'm looking at a jmap dump (hprof format) with various tools.

VisualVM (and NetBeans profiler based tools) reports differ a lot from Yourkit and Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

I looked at the most simple objects, and even those differ... for java.lang.Integer, VisualVm reports 20 bytes, instead of 16 as the others (that in my interpretation is because = 12 bytes header + 4 bytes int 'value' filed from the Integer class = 16, no padding needed).

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: You are right. Maybe mentioned should be the `valueOf` cache for -128 to 127 or configurably higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only correct tool to use is [JOL](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/), all others might be inaccurate.

And that reports `16 bytes` : 12 for headers + 4 for `int` itself (so you are correct).

```
  Integer i = 42;

  System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(i).toPrintable());
```

I am leaving it to you to run this code and see the output yourself. Just notice that it could have been more, if `UseCompressedOops` would have been disabled; in such a case there would be an extra `4 bytes` + extra `4 bytes` for padding.